# Как подключать библиотеки из других проектов

Tags: c++, include

В коде на гитхабе нашел  следующую строку.

```
#include <sodium/crypto_hash_sha256.h>
```

Не совсем понятно как подключить эту либу. В c# это делалось путем добавления проекта и указания ссылки на него. В с++  как я понимаю это делается по другому. 
Я добавил в каталог библиотек путь к папке с проектом `libsodium`, но оно все равно не видит этот `include`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На вашем скрине идете в C/C++ -> общие -> дополнительные каталоги включения. И добавляете туда каталог, который содержит "sodium/crypto_hash_sha256.h". Это для инклюда. А еще, скорее всего, нужно будет добавить lib-файл в проект.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто - добавьте путь к `libsоdium` в каталоги включения. При этом каталог включения должен указывать на папку содержащую `sodium`

Короче держи мануал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059167/3640470